# Ruby: Decorator pattern slows simple program by a lot

Tags: ruby

I recently wrote a program to return a bunch of stocks from the stock market that are unhealthy. The basic algorithm is this:

1. Look up all the quotes of every stock in an exchange (either NYSE or NASDAQ)
2. Find the ones that are less than 5 dollars from step 1
3. Find the ones from step 2 that are down 3 days and have large volume (expensive because I have to make a request for each stock, which is like ~700 currently for nasdaq).
4. Scan the news for the ones returned by step 3.

I had this all in one file:

Original implementation (https://github.com/EdmundMai/minion/blob/aa14bc3234a4953e7273ec502276c6f0073b459d/lib/minion.rb):

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require "minion/version"
require "yahoo-finance"
require "business_time"
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

module Minion
  class << self
    def query(exchange)
      client = YahooFinance::Client.new
      all_companies = CSV.read("#{exchange}.csv")

      small_caps = []

      ticker_symbols = all_companies.map { |row| row[0] }
      ticker_symbols.each_slice(200) do |batch|
        data = client.quotes(batch, [:symbol, :last_trade_price, :average_daily_volume])
        small_caps << data.select { |stock| stock.last_trade_price.to_f < 5.0 }
      end

      attractive = []

      small_caps.flatten!.each_with_index do |small_cap, index|
        begin
          data = client.historical_quotes(small_cap.symbol, { start_date: 2.business_days.ago, end_date: Time.now })
          closing_prices = data.map(&:close).map(&:to_f)
          volumes = data.map(&:volume).map(&:to_i)

          negative_3_days_in_a_row = closing_prices == closing_prices.sort
          larger_than_average_volume = volumes.reduce(:+) / volumes.count > small_cap.average_daily_volume.to_i

          if negative_3_days_in_a_row && larger_than_average_volume
            attractive << small_cap.symbol
            puts "Qualified: #{small_cap.symbol}, finished with #{index} out of #{small_caps.count}"
          else
            puts "Not qualified: #{small_cap.symbol}, finished with #{index} out of #{small_caps.count}"
          end
        rescue => e
          puts e.inspect
        end
      end

      final_results = []

      attractive.each do |symbol|
        rss_feed = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=#{symbol}&region=US&lang=en-US"))
        html_body = rss_feed.css('body')[0].text
        diluting = false
        ['warrant', 'cashless exercise'].each do |keyword|
          diluting = true if html_body.match(/#{keyword}/i)
        end
        final_results << symbol if diluting
      end

      final_results
    end
  end
end
```

This was really fast and would finish processing like ~700 stocks in a minute or less.

Then, I tried refactoring and splitting up the algorithm into different classes and files without changing the algorithm at all. I decided on using the decorator pattern since it seems to fit. However when I run the program now, it makes each request really slowly (15+ min). I know this because my `puts` statements get printed out really slowly.

New and slower implementation (https://github.com/EdmundMai/minion/blob/master/lib/minion.rb)

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require "minion/version"
require "yahoo-finance"
require "minion/dilution_finder"
require "minion/negative_finder"
require "minion/small_cap_finder"
require "minion/market_fetcher"

module Minion
  class << self
    def query(exchange)
      all_companies = CSV.read("#{exchange}.csv")
      all_tickers = all_companies.map { |row| row[0] }

      short_finder = DilutionFinder.new(NegativeFinder.new(SmallCapFinder.new(MarketFetcher.new(all_tickers))))
      short_finder.results
    end
  end
end
```

The part it's lagging at according to my `puts`:

```
require "yahoo-finance"
require "business_time"
require_relative "stock_finder"

class NegativeFinder < StockFinder
  def results
    client = YahooFinance::Client.new
    results = []
    finder.results.each_with_index do |stock, index|
      begin
        data = client.historical_quotes(stock.symbol, { start_date: 2.business_days.ago, end_date: Time.now })
        closing_prices = data.map(&:close).map(&:to_f)
        volumes = data.map(&:volume).map(&:to_i)

        negative_3_days_in_a_row = closing_prices == closing_prices.sort
        larger_than_average_volume = volumes.reduce(:+) / volumes.count > stock.average_daily_volume.to_i

        if negative_3_days_in_a_row && larger_than_average_volume
          results << stock
          puts "Qualified: #{stock.symbol}, finished with #{index} out of #{finder.results.count}"
        else
          puts "Not qualified: #{stock.symbol}, finished with #{index} out of #{finder.results.count}"
        end
      rescue => e
        puts e.inspect
      end
    end
    results
  end
end
```

It's lagging on step 3 (making one request for each stock). Not sure what's going on so any advice would be appreciated. If you want to clone the program and run it, just comment in the last line in lib/minion.rb and type `ruby lib/minion.rb`

Comment: It sounds like your scripts make a lot of calls to Yahoo Finance. Are you sure you're not getting rate limited?

Comment: Yeh @SunilD. When I reverted my changes and then ran it again and it was fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debugging it I figured it out. It was because I was calling `finder.results` (results being the decorated method) inside of the loop as shown below:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require "minion/version"
require "yahoo-finance"
require "minion/dilution_finder"
require "minion/negative_finder"
require "minion/small_cap_finder"
require "minion/market_fetcher"

module Minion
  class << self
    def query(exchange)
      all_companies = CSV.read("#{exchange}.csv")
      all_tickers = all_companies.map { |row| row[0] }

      short_finder = DilutionFinder.new(NegativeFinder.new(SmallCapFinder.new(MarketFetcher.new(all_tickers))))
      short_finder.results
    end
  end
end
```

The part it's lagging at according to my `puts`:

```
require "yahoo-finance"
require "business_time"
require_relative "stock_finder"

class NegativeFinder < StockFinder
  def results
    client = YahooFinance::Client.new
    results = []
    finder.results.each_with_index do |stock, index|
      begin
        data = client.historical_quotes(stock.symbol, { start_date: 2.business_days.ago, end_date: Time.now })
        closing_prices = data.map(&:close).map(&:to_f)
        volumes = data.map(&:volume).map(&:to_i)

        negative_3_days_in_a_row = closing_prices == closing_prices.sort
        larger_than_average_volume = volumes.reduce(:+) / volumes.count > stock.average_daily_volume.to_i

        if negative_3_days_in_a_row && larger_than_average_volume
          results << stock
          // HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
          puts "Qualified: #{stock.symbol}, finished with #{index} out of #{finder.results.count}" <------------------------------------
        else
          // AND HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
          puts "Not qualified: #{stock.symbol}, finished with #{index} out of #{finder.results.count}" <-----------------------------------------------------------
        end
      rescue => e
        puts e.inspect
      end
    end
    results
  end
end
```

This caused a cascade of requests every time I iterated through the loop in `NegativeFinder`. Removing that call fixed it. Lesson: When using the decorator pattern, either only call the decorated method once, especially when you're doing something expensive in each call. Either that or hold the returned variable in an instance variable so you don't have to calculate it each time.

Also as a side note, I've decided not to go with the decorator pattern because I don't think it applies well here. Something like `SmallCapFinder.new(SmallCapFinder.new(MarketFetcher.new(all_tickers)))` doesn't add functionality at all (the primary function of using the decorator pattern), so chaining decorators doesn't do anything. Therefore, I'm just going to make them methods instead of adding unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 1):

There are some thing missing in the code you gave us (Base class StockFinder, MarketFetcher). But I think you are now instantate more than one  YahooFinance::Client.  Input/Output to other systems is very often the cause for speed problems.

I suggest that you first encapsulate the finance client and access to financial data. This makes it easier when you want to switch your financial data provider, or add another one. Instead of the decorator pattern, I would just use plain old methods for finding small caps, finding negative, etc.

Comment: yeh i was planning on using the adapter pattern too after i got this bug fixed. thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: p.s. i figured it out